# Yahoo Account Key Problem

Tags: account-security

I have a problem with my Yahoo Account because Account Key blocks me from logging in to my account.

My fault is that I reformatted my phone while my Account Key was on. Now I don't have access to my account key and that's the only one that I use as my account recovery.

I also put my phone number on my account, but I lost my SIM card and I also don't have a recovery email.

I still can access my Facebook account using that email though.

I searched many times on how to recover my account and removed that Account Key from Yahoo. But no hope. I also wish to remove that Account Key and change it to a password instead.

So how can Yahoo can help me with my problem if I can't contact them? Can Facebook help me with my problem?

Comment: I think your best bet is getting that phone number back, even if it's on another SIM card. Without that, the only proof you have is a Facebook account. Who tells Yahoo (or us...) that you're not a blackhat, who cracked someone else's FB account, and now tries to get more? Not saying you're a blackhat, but the possibility exists - neither we nor Yahoo can tell.